# httpd graceful restart - syntax error

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, freeipa

Found this on my httpd server

```
[pid 18582] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-nss.conf: Cannot load modules/libmodnss.so into server: /lib64/libnssutil3.so: version `NSSUTIL_3.82' not found (required by /lib64/libnss3.so)
```

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-nss.conf:
LoadModule nss_module modules/libmodnss.so
```

I've verified the files exists, after a manually restart of Httpd it was back.
`httpd -t` reports syntax OK